# USACO: Task Checker Challenge

Tags: java

--UPDATE--

I solved this by rewriting in C++ and submitting. Not exactly the most prestigious way to go about it, but it sure did work!

--END UPDATE--

I am doing the USACO checker problem, and gosh I am on the verge of pulling my hair out! I have a solution but it is off by about .3 seconds for the last test case (n=13). Is there any way the program below to run faster?

If there is anything that I can add to help, please let me know!

EDIT: The program must run <1 second w/compilation.

```
import java.io.*;
class checker
{
    static int n;
    static boolean ifCol[];
    static boolean rDiag[] = new boolean [26];
    static boolean lDiag[] = new boolean [26];
    static int col[];
    static int print;
    static int counter;
    static PrintWriter out;
    private static void search (int row)
    {
        if (row == n)
        {
            if (print < 3)
            {
                out.print (col [0] + 1);
                for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
                    out.print (" " + (col [i] + 1));
                out.println ();
                print++;
            }
            counter++;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            if (!ifCol [i] && !rDiag [i - row + 13] && !lDiag [i + row])
            {
                ifCol [i] = rDiag [i - row + 13] = lDiag [i + row] = true;
                col [row] = i;
                search (row + 1);
                ifCol [i] = rDiag [i - row + 13] = lDiag [i + row] = false;
            }

        }
        return;
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //long start = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("checker.in"));
        out = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("checker.out")));
        n = Integer.parseInt (in.readLine ());
        col = new int [n];
        ifCol = new boolean [n];
        search (0);
        out.println (counter);
        //out.println (System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
        out.close ();
        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

PROBLEM STATEMENT:
Checker Challenge

Examine the 6x6 checkerboard below and note that the six checkers are arranged on the board so that one and only one is placed in each row and each column, and there is never more than one in any diagonal. (Diagonals run from southeast to northwest and southwest to northeast and include all diagonals, not just the major two.)

```
      Column
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

---

1 |   | O |   |   |   |   |

---

2 |   |   |   | O |   |   |

---

3 |   |   |   |   |   | O |

---

4 | O |   |   |   |   |   |

---

5 |   |   | O |   |   |   |

---

6 |   |   |   |   | O |   |

---

The solution shown above is described by the sequence 2 4 6 1 3 5, which gives the column positions of the checkers for each row from 1 to 6:

ROW 1   2   3   4   5   6
COLUMN  2   4   6   1   3   5
This is one solution to the checker challenge. Write a program that finds all unique solution sequences to the Checker Challenge (with ever growing values of N). Print the solutions using the column notation described above. Print the the first three solutions in numerical order, as if the checker positions form the digits of a large number, and then a line with the total number of solutions.

Special note: the larger values of N require your program to be especially efficient. Do not precalculate the value and print it (or even find a formula for it); that's cheating. Work on your program until it can solve the problem properly. If you insist on cheating, your login to the USACO training pages will be removed and you will be disqualified from all USACO competitions. YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED.

TIME LIMIT: 1 CPU second

PROGRAM NAME: checker

INPUT FORMAT

A single line that contains a single integer N (6 <= N <= 13) that is the dimension of the N x N checkerboard.
SAMPLE INPUT (file checker.in)

6

OUTPUT FORMAT

The first three lines show the first three solutions found, presented as N numbers with a single space between them. The fourth line shows the total number of solutions found.
SAMPLE OUTPUT (file checker.out)

2 4 6 1 3 5

3 6 2 5 1 4

4 1 5 2 6 3

4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it in C instead of Java.

I was in the same situation as you, and after laboring on the problem for about an hour, I decided to switch languages.

I didn't even change my algorithm, and it ran 10 times faster.

(After you get past the challenge you can read the analysis and see what other optimizations you could have made.)

I know that this is a really late reply and you probably forgot about this problem ages ago.......
:)

Comment: Actually no I didn't. I actually did rewrite this problem in C++ and got it accepted (barely though). C would have been better, but this was a long time ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd observe that the problem reduces to enumerating all permutations of the integers 1 to N except the ordered sequences 1 to N and N to 1 (which represent the diagonals).  There are many texts on algorithms that will generate permutations for you.

Comment: Taking your advice, I used a nonrecursive heap permutation generation. It ended up taking me 3.2 seconds. This is probably because the algorithm doesn't fit in well with the type of search that I am doing :S

Comment: Why are you performing a search?

Comment: Because I am unable to use a formula to generate an answer. It has to be done with some type of recursion/BFS/iterative deepening etc.

Comment: I believe that an algorithm which generates the permutations is sufficient: it should not be necessary to perform a further "search", as we know that the permutations are valid.

Comment: Not All permutations are valid... Only a certain set meet the requirements.

Comment: Ah, I'd overlooked the constraint that "diagonals run from southeast to northwest and southwest to northeast and _include all diagonals, not just the major two_".  Such diagonals are represented by rotations of the major diagonal sequences mentioned in my answer above (e.g. 345612 and 321654 are minor diagonals NW-SE and SW-NE respectively): therefore the "search" merely need check whether more than one digit within each permutation matches any of the diagonals; or perhaps you can use this information to modify the permutation generation algorithm such that no search is required at all?

Comment: Luckily, i have already got it in time (ported the code to C++ *sighs* I lost) oh well. Furthermore, I think I can edit the permutation generator in a way such that the returned values hold true. I will look into that.